# awk sub() of a substring by position

Tags: bash, awk

if I have the following:

```
>ID_10_J_X
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ
```

(i.e. a fasta file!)

I want to be able to locate a substring based on the position (2nd element of first like i.e. 10) and take n positions around it i.e. 5 positions

```
EFGHIJKLMNO
```

and then substitute the position of interest with the 4th element of line 1 - i.e. X:

```
EFGHIXKLMNO
```

I can locate the substring, which is fine...but I am having trouble using the elements of line 1 to make the substitution in line 2. I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '

/>/{split($0,M,"_")}     
!/^>/{split($1,N,"")
print M[1]"_"M[2]"_"M[3]"_"M[4]"\n"substr($1,M[2]-5,10)}

' $1
```

which gets me my substring.

Could someone help with my logic here to make the substitution. I gather I can use the `sub()` function and call the substring directly. My thinking is to use:

```
sub(regex/position,replacement,target)
```

which in my example would translate as:

```
sub(N[2],N[4],substr($1,M[2]-5,10))
```

Trying this results in

```
awk: cmd. line:5: print sub(M[2],M[4],substr($1,M[2]-10,20))}
awk: cmd. line:5:                                          ^ sub third parameter is not a changeable object
```

So it seems I cannot call the substring explictly, and I alos have doubts about being able to use the position elements in the regex parameter.

Could someone help me with my code to form a general solution? My input is

```
>ID_10_J_X
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ
```

and desired output is:

```
EFGHIXKLMNO
```

where I will have many inputs in the same file.

It must also hold true that, although I am looking for a substring consisting of 5 positions either side of the position given in line 1, if the position in line 1 is < 5, the substitution must be made in the specified position i.e.

```
>ID_2_J_X
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ

AXCDEFG
```

It would be nice (but not essential) if the final substring is always a certain length i.e. if I have specified a substring of 10, but the substition is in position 2 as above, 8 characters are selected after the substitution to complete the a substring of length 10

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This awk script produces your desired output:

```
awk -F_ '/^>/{p=$2;s=$NF;next}{print substr($0,p-5,5) s substr($0,p+1,5)}' file
```

The first block saves your position `p` and replacement character `s`. The second prints the 5 characters before `p`, the replacement character, then the 5 characters after `p`.

Demo:

```
$ cat file
>ID_10_J_X
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ
$ awk -F_ '/^>/{p=$2;s=$NF;next}{print substr($0,p-5,5) s substr($0,p+1,5)}' file
EFGHIXKLMNO
```

---

Here's an updated version of the code to deal with positions that are closer than 5 characters away from the start or end of the line. As it's slightly longer, I've used a script rather than a one-liner for clarity. You can run it like `awk -f script.awk file`:

```
BEGIN { FS="_" }
/^>/ {
    p=$2; c=$NF; next
}
{
    if (p-5<1) s=1
    else if (p+5>length($0)) s=length($0)-10
    else s=p-5
    print substr($0,s,p-s) c substr($0,p,11-p+s)
}
```

Testing it out:

```
$ cat file
>ID_2_J_X
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ
>ID_10_J_X
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ
>ID_22_J_X
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ
$ awk -f script.awk file
AXBCDEFGHIJK
EFGHIXJKLMNO
PQRSTUXVQXYZ
```